# Does cmd always open a new window when you md

Tags: java, windows, cmd, mkdir

I am in the midst of a Java project, part of which is calling the Windows cmd to make a directory.  My code currently looks like this:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String command;
    command = "cmd.exe /c start mkdir \"C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\Folder1\\"+folderName+"\" &&exit";
    rt.exec(command);
```

This works fine (creates the folder), but it spawns an additional instance of cmd.  (I originally added the "&&exit" thinking it would eliminate the extra window, but I now realize it is unnecessary code.)

1) Can I prevent this additional instance of cmd (which begins in the new directory), or

2) Can I close this extra cmd window without causing other problems?    (I have heard that killing cmd can break other things on a machine.)

Comment: You don't need to run an external command to create a directory. Use the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\Folder1\\"+folderName+"\"");

    if(!file.exists())
    {
        file.mkdir();
    }
```

instead. However, if you want to call the command into cmd without creating a new one, you should not call "cmd.exe /c start". You can check that if you run that very same command from outside java it will also start a new cmd. Try this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String command;
command = "mkdir \"C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\Folder1\\"+folderName+"\" &&exit";
rt.exec(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create the dir with `File`?

```
new File("C:\\my\\path\\myDir").mkdir();
```

Comment: We should start recommending doing it the NIO way. `Files.createDirectory(Path, FileAttributes)`